# Android application doesn't work in emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, android-logcat

I'm developing an android application and after I hit run, I unlock the AVD and click the menu to load my application and I immediately get this message: `The application Pico TTS (process com.svox..pico) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again`

This my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:allowBackup="true">
        <activity android:name=".MPActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

These are the messages from my logcat:

```
10-09 13:01:14.796: I/TextToSpeech.java(1861): initTts() successfully bound to service
10-09 13:01:16.916: E/ActivityThread(1861): Activity com.kelamrsan.MPActivity has leaked ServiceConnection android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$1@4051d710 that was originally bound here
10-09 13:01:16.916: E/ActivityThread(1861): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity com.kelamrsan.MPActivity has leaked ServiceConnection android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$1@4051d710 that was originally bound here
10-09 13:01:16.916: E/ActivityThread(1861):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:938)
10-09 13:01:16.916: E/ActivityThread(1861):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:833)
10-09 13:01:16.916: E/ActivityThread(1861):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:347)
10-09 13:01:16.916: E/ActivityThread(1861):     at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.initTts(TextToSpeech.java:467)
10-09 13:01:16.916: E/ActivityThread(1861):     at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.<init>(TextToSpeech.java:433)
10-09 13:01:16.916: E/ActivityThread(1861):     at com.kelamrsan.MPActivity.onCreate(MPActivity.java:47)
10-09 13:01:16.916: E/ActivityThread(1861):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-09 13:01:16.916: E/ActivityThread(1861):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
10-09 13:01:16.916: E/ActivityThread(1861):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
10-09 13:01:16.916: E/ActivityThread(1861):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
10-09 13:01:16.916: E/ActivityThread(1861):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
10-09 13:01:16.916: E/ActivityThread(1861):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-09 13:01:16.916: E/ActivityThread(1861):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
10-09 13:01:16.916: E/ActivityThread(1861):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
10-09 13:01:16.916: E/ActivityThread(1861):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-09 13:01:16.916: E/ActivityThread(1861):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-09 13:01:16.916: E/ActivityThread(1861):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-09 13:01:16.916: E/ActivityThread(1861):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-09 13:01:16.916: E/ActivityThread(1861):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This my `onCreate`:

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);
     Button buttonLoadImage = (Button)findViewById(R.id.loadimage);

 textView    = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
 textViewCol = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewColor);
 targetImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.targetimage);
 textViewVal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewValue);

  mTts = new TextToSpeech(this, new OnInitListener() {      
    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
    TTSInitialized = true;
    }
  });

  Intent installIntent = new Intent();
  installIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
  startActivity(installIntent);

 buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Intent intent = new   Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
  startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
 }});

}
```

So where do you think the problem is?!

Comment: problem is here: at com.kelamrsan.MPActivity.onCreate(MPActivity.java:47)

Comment: I appreciate your concern, Kuffs.
But I can't get the problem, everything was working perfect before.
However, I have updated the questions and added onCreate codes here. See if you can find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are creating the TTS object passing in the current activity as a context.

You then immediately start a new activity (and I assume do not close down the TTS object in your OnPause)

This makes the system complain because you have an active service that is tied to a now non-active activity.

You should use the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html) callbacks to set up and tear down any services that depend on the activity.

e.g Set up your TTS object in OnResume() and close it down in OnPause()

Comment: That should be it. So can you tell me how to do it. I'm pretty much a newbie in this.

Comment: close your TTS service when the activity pauses. In your case, don't even start it as you are not using it due to you immediately passing control to a new activity.

Comment: See this: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html Don't ever assume that a variable that was active when you leave an activity (In your case the mTts) will still be there when you return. The system can close things down when it needs to.

Comment: I will try my best, see how it goes. Again, I appreciate it. Your answer is quite useful and accepted.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though you have a broadcast listener that gets loaded once and then does not get released as expected.  If this is the case, then you would need to analyze the life-cycle of your application covering that broadcast receiver and be sure that it is closed for a previous launch of the activity.  If needed you can even surround it in a try catch when you create the broadcast and do nothing.  As Android will take care of the conflict for you and silently fail if all else fails; obviously finding the appropriate close would be ideal.

That's all that I can deduce from what is provided.